# Convert byte array or strinbuilder to utf-8

Tags: java

i want to convert the content to utf-8 charset before i return the string in following method:

```
public static String getContentResult(URL url) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];

    while(true){
        int byteRead = in.read(buffer);
        if(byteRead == -1)
            break;
        for(int i = 0; i < byteRead; i++){
            sb.append((char)buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW: You are converting text as `ISO-8859-1` encoding into a String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to convert *to* UTF-8. You want (I believe) to interpret the incoming stream of data *as* UTF-8.

Options:

- Create an `InputStreamReader` wrapping your incoming stream, specifying UTF-8, and read blocks of *characters* at a time, appending to a `StringBuilder`

  ```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  char[] buffer = new char[4096];
  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
  int charsRead;
  while ((charsRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      builder.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
  }
  ```
- Use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to read the whole data as a byte array, then convert it in one go:

  ```
  byte[] data = BytesStreams.toByteArray(in);
  return new String(data, Charsets.UTF_8);
  ```

In either case, you should use a `finally` block to close the stream, so that you close it even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: if stream is converted to java String, automatically it will have encoding `UTF-16` because `java String represents a string in the UTF-16 format`?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first alternative and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: @NandkumarTekale: What do you mean by "it will have encoding"? You need to specify the encoding you want to use when interpreting the stream. The string itself is always *effectively* in UTF-16, but you should *think* of it as just text.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thanks Jon, I read on javadoc that `String represents a string in the UTF-16 format`. So if we are converting stream to string, then it is in `UTF-16`. I was confirming it from you.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale: The problem is what you mean by "it" - your question was ambiguous. But yes, you can think of a string as being a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 0):

Convert from String to byte[]:

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Convert from byte[] to String:

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 99, (byte)97, (byte)116};
String s = new String(b, "US-ASCII");
```

Comment: if you want to add the actual byte value don't use "US-ASCII" just leave that parameter off: `byte[] abcd={'A','B','C','D',13,10,'E','F',(byte)255,'G','H',13,10,'J','K',0,'L','M'};
  String s = new String(abcd);
  StringBuilder sabcd=new StringBuilder();
  
  sabcd.append(s);
  System.out.println(sabcd);
  for(int i=0;i<sabcd.length();i++) {
   char c=sabcd.charAt(i);
   System.out.println((int)c);
  }`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add the actual byte value don't use "US-ASCII" just leave that parameter off:

```
byte[] abcd={'A','B','C','D',13,10,'E','F',(byte)255,'G','H',13,10,'J','K',0,'L','M'};
String s = new String(abcd);
StringBuilder sabcd=new StringBuilder();

sabcd.append(s);
System.out.println(sabcd);
for(int i=0;i<sabcd.length();i++) {
    char c=sabcd.charAt(i);
    System.out.println((int)c);
}
```

Result:

```
ABCD
EFÿGH
JK
65
66
67
68
13
10
69
70
255
71
72
13
10
74
75
0
76
77
```